# virtual environment from Mac to Linux

Tags: python, django, linux, macos, virtualenv

I recently made a django project using virtualenv on my mac. That mac broke, but I saved the files and now I want to work on my project using my linux computer. I am now having some difficulty running the virtual environment in Ubuntu.

Does it even make sense to try and use a virtual env made in Mac OS on Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just recreate the virtual environment on Ubuntu.  The virtual env will have the python binary which will be different on a different system.

Comment: do you mean i should rerun the virtual environment process: $ virtualenv ENVName?

Comment: Yeah.  Make a new virtual environment.  Source it.  Try to run your code.  If you get an import error, `pip install <missing module>`.  Once you get everything installed and running, `pip freeze > requirements.txt` so that setting up your next virtualenv is easier (if this were to happen again)

Answer (score 2):

## Install pip

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

## Install virtualenv using pip

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

## Create a virtual environment

```
virtualenv venv
```

### You can use any name instead of venv.

### You can also use a Python interpreter of your choice

```
virtualenv -p <python2> <python3> <python3.7> venv
```

## Activate your virtual environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

You only have to recreate virtualenv. That's all.

## If you have a requirements.txt file then use pip to install the requirements:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```